# Get the date by hovering over a day in monthsView

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I use FullCalendar in monthsView.

I would get the date when I hover a day in the calendar.
To say it differently, I want to the same thing like the event dayClicking but just by hoving a day.
I test many different ways with no success ...

I have tried the following function:

```
JQ('body').on('mouseover', 'td.fc-day', function() {
    console.log("OK");
}),
```

I also try the solutions found in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22494628/fullcalendar-td-fc-day-mouseover-sometimes-get-wrong-date-on-small-month-ca)
but any solution works for me ...

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You were so close, every `fc-day` & `fc-day-number` have a data-date attribute filled in with the actual date:

```
$('body').on('mouseover', 'td.fc-day, td.fc-day-number', function() {
    console.log($(this).data('date'));
});
```

If you have background events they will render above all the day cells. Because of that the mouseover will not respond. If you add the following CSS the mouseover events go though those background event elements.

```
.fc-bgevent-skeleton{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjs29gh1/1/)

Comment: `$(this).data('date');` is more `jQuery`

Comment: @willy3cub I added a fiddle showing the functionality.

Comment: Ok I found the origin of the problem : It works when there are only basics event in the calendar. But It doesn't work when there are background events ... You can check on the fullCalendar website : [BasicEvent](http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.3.1/demos/basic-views.html) [BackroundEvent](http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.3.1/demos/background-events.html)

Comment: @willy3cub are you interested in a fix for that also?

Comment: @willy3cub updated my answer with a more consistent solution ;)